# Finding polygon neighbors using intersect function with added conditions

Tags: expression, aggregate

Using `aggregate()` in field calculator, I tried to find neighboring polygons. The polygons have a field `type` with two values: `new` and `old`. I want to find neighbors of the type `old`. Hence, I tried the below code
source: https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/04/08/calculating-shared-border-lengths/

```
array_to_string(
  array_remove_all(
    aggregate(
      layer:= 'union_2001_2011f',
      aggregate:='array_agg',
      expression:=Id,
      filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)) AND "type" = 'old'
    ),
    "Id" 
  )
)
```

The above code works perfectly without the condition `AND "type" = 'old'`.

Also, I adapted the same code and worked with a dummy dataset. It worked perfectly there.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE! The syntax seems ok to me. About the field, is the "type" field in the 'union_2001_2011f' layer? About the values, maybe some space character... You can try `AND "type" LIKE '%old%'`.

Comment: Your expression works fine with me. Can you share your project/data? At least a sample of it. There could be a lot of different reasons why it does not work in your case.

Comment: Thank you @Babel . I made a blunder mistake. The field value was not "old"